# Equivalent function to sscanf in Vlang

Tags: vlang

Title says it all; looking for an equivalent to sscanf in vlang.

Go (which Vlang is similar to), has fmt.sscanf; but I don't see anything similar in the Vlang docs.

The somewhat closest method I could find is [find_between](https://modules.vlang.io/index.html#string.find_between); but I'd have to call it successive times if I have numerous elements to pull out of a string.

Comment: Why should behave sscanf function is you can use the following syntax '$var_q:$var_e'?

Answer (score 1):

In V there is no need of this type of function because you can format your string with the following syntax `'$var_q:$var_e'`

This is a real code example of the v compiler

```
fn run_repl(workdir string, vrepl_prefix string) {
    if !is_stdin_a_pipe {
        println(version.full_v_version(false))
        println('Use Ctrl-C or ${term.highlight_command('exit')} to exit, or ${term.highlight_command('help')} to see other available commands')
    }
// .. other repl code
}
```

Comment: That's not how sscanf works,  you're thinking printf. Sscanf scans a string with a format and puts the respective specifiers (%d, %s, etc) into variables.

Comment: damt, you are right! I need to fix this shit! thanks to ping me on this!